# Feeding multiple values into a function from array, but only for a single argument

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

This is a bit of a newbie question which I'm sure has been answered somewhere already but unfortunately I could not find it anywhere.

I have a function,`findDX`, that takes in an `Nx2` numpy array, `D`, and a single float `X` (definition provided below). I want to evaluate this function on a fixed`D` with multiple values of `X`,
i.e. `find_DX(D, 1)`,`find_DX(D, 2)`,`find_DX(D, 3)` where the array of `X` inputs is `[1,2,3]`

Is there a way to pass in multiple values of X while keeping D fixed (other than changing the function definition)? I have tried

```
find_DX([mcm],[1,2,3])
```

but this predictably gives a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`

```
def find_DX(D, X):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    D : numpy array
        Input cumulative DVH.
    X : Float
       We're finding the dose recieved by at least X% of tissues.

    Returns
    -------
    DX

    """
    idx = (np.abs(D[:,1] - X)).argmin()
    return D[idx,0]
```

EDIT: I just wrote a loop for it. I was hoping to avoid having to do so but it does the job. I have posted my new function below if anyone wants to use it:

```
def find_DX(cDVH, X_values):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    cDVH : numpy array
        Input array
    X : numpy array
       Values of X to evaluate.

    """
    X_values=np.float64(X_values) #force to float
    Out=np.zeros_like(X_values)
    for i in range(0,len(X_values)):
        idx = np.abs(cDVH[:,1] - X_values[i]).argmin()
        Out[i]=cDVH[idx,0]

    return tuple(Out)
```

Comment: You want to do `idx = (np.abs(D[:,1] - X)).argmin()` for` x =1,x=2,x=3` like that?

Comment: Yep! I want the function to feed in the X inputs one by one and evaluate the return statement for a given array D. I've tried passing them as a list and a tuple but this also ends with Value Errors, I guess I'm not quite sure how to tell Python to use the values in the list [1,2,3] one by one instead of just defining X=[1,2,3] and then trying to evaluate the function.

Comment: You have to use loop to get elements one by one. And return as an array

Comment: Ah ok, I was hoping to avoid having to specify a for loop but I suppose I will just do that. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can call the function multiple times using `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
import numpy as np

def find_DX(D, X):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    D : numpy array
        Input cumulative DVH.
    X : Float
       We're finding the dose recieved by at least X% of tissues.

    Returns
    -------
    DX

    """
    tmpArr=[]
    for i in X:
        idx = (np.abs(D[:,1] - i)).argmin()
        tmpArr.append(idx)
    return tmpArr

a = [[1,2],[2,3]]   #sample array
a= np.array(a)

print(find_DX(a,[1,2,3]))
```